# how to store an store an integer from an existing string

Tags: c, arrays, string, integer

I'm wondering how I can store cut an integer and store it into an array or variable(in this case 'i'). SO my question is how would I store number 34 and 53 to i and j.

```
int main(void) {
    char str[80] = "qwerty,34,53";
    int i,j;

}
```

Comment: `char[80] = " ... "` is wrong, so you mean `char str[80] = ...`?

Comment: yep sorry thats what i meant

Comment: `sscanf(str, "%*[^,],%d,%d", &i, &j);`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to split the string. Use [`strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) for this job.

Afterwards, convert the appropriate substrings to integers with [`atoi()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that, example

```
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *head;
    char  str[80] = "qwerty,34,53";
    int   i;
    int   j;

    head = strchr(str, ','); /* first make head, point to the `,' */
    if (head == NULL) /* Check that it was found */
        return -1;
    /* Now use `strtol()' to extract the integers */
    i = strtol(head + 1, &head, 10);
    j = strtol(head + 1, &head, 10);

    printf("i = %d, j = %d\n", i, j);
    return 0;
}
```

This works, because `strtol()` will stop when it finds a non numeric character, and `head` ends up pointing to the `,`, of course this works in this simple case, also there could be spaces between the `,` and the values, because `strtol()` will ignore them.